# Como pintar determinadas linhas em um totalcross.ui.Grid

Tags: totalcross

Ao preencher um Grid do Totalcross, eu possuo registros condicionados que devem ficar destacados em relação aos demais. Eu pensei em trocar a cor da linha, ou mostrar a fonte em negrito.

O Grid por padrão mostra as linhas "zebradas" com as cores branco e cinza intercaladas e que podem ser facilmente modificadas com os atributos firstStripeColor e secondStripeColor, além da linha quando selecionada, com highlightColor. Essas alternativas não me atendem, pois eu posso ter registros em sequencia para serem destacados. Procurei um pouco na documentação e encontrei a classe totalcross.ui.Grid.CellController, essa talvez atendesse mas não encontrei nenhum exemplo de como utiliza-la.

Será que é possível utilizar a CellController para isso, ou existe alguma outra alternativa somente com a Grid?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Implementação:

1. Criei uma classe e estendi a CellController, e no construtor recebo um array de inteiros primitivo que indica qual a posição deve ser destacada, e no método getBackColor() verifico se a posição da linha com valor igual a 1 e atribuindo a cor vermelha:

> `public class GridController extends CellController {
>       int[] highlight;
>       public GridController(int[] highlight) {
>           this.highlight = highlight;
>       }
>       @Override
>       public int getBackColor(int row, int col) {
>           return (highlight[row] == 1) ? Color.RED : -1;
>       }
>       @Override
>       public String[] getChoices(int arg0, int arg1) {
>           return null;
>       }
>       @Override
>       public int getForeColor(int arg0, int arg1) {
>           return 0;
>       }
>       @Override
>       public boolean isEnabled(int arg0, int arg1) {
>           return true;
>       }
>   }`

E para usar, crio um array de inteiros com o tamanho da lista, e dentro do laço na condição desejada atribuo o valor 1 que será a condição para a linha ser destacada, instancio a classe GridController criada antes e seto na grid :

> `private void buildGrid() {
>       int highlight[] = new int[lista.size()];
>       for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
>           X x = lista[i];
>           if (x.getOverdue().isAfter(x.getDueDate()))
>               highlight[i] = 1;
>           grid.add(new String[] { x.getId(), x.getDescricao() });
>       }
>       GridController gridController = new GridController(highlight);
>       grid.setCellController(gridController);
>       repaint();
>   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, o `Grid.CellController` permite o controle do jeito que você desejar.

Se você baixou o TotalCross do site, então deve ter percebido uma pasta `src` no lugar em que você instala ele. Dentro de lá, procure por `src/main/java/tc/samples/api/ui/GridSample.java`.

De todo caso, vamos examinar com calma o `Grid.CellController`.

```
public static abstract class CellController {

  public abstract int getForeColor(int row, int col);
  public abstract int getBackColor(int row, int col);
  public abstract String[] getChoices(int row, int col);
  public abstract boolean isEnabled(int row, int col);

  public Font getFont(int row, int col) {return null;}
}
```

Para cada método, é passado um número de linha/*row* e coluna/*col*. Isso significa que é possível pulverizar do jeito adequado os seus dados. Conhecendo a linha e a coluna, você pode definir individualmente qual a cor de fundo `getBackColor` e qual a cor de frente/a cor que se imprime o texto `getForeColor`.

Os outros métodos, por enquanto, parecem supérfluos pro seu uso.

### Exemplos

Vou por aqui 4 exemplos de `CellController` e seus respectivos screenshots para você se basear.

```
CellController colunas = new CellController() {
    @Override
    public int getForeColor(int row, int col) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBackColor(int row, int col) {
        return (col % 2 == 0) ? 0xffffff : 0xe0e0e0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getChoices(int row, int col) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

[image: grid de colunas marcadas]

```
CellController tresDois_doisTres = new CellController() {
    @Override
    public int getForeColor(int row, int col) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBackColor(int row, int col) {
        int threshold;
        if ((row / 5) % 2 == 0) {
            threshold = 3;
        } else {
            threshold = 2;
        }

        return (row % 5) < threshold ? 0xffffff : 0xe0e0e0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getChoices(int row, int col) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

[image: alternando: 3 linhas brancas e 2 linhas cinzas, depois 2 linhas brancas e 3 linhas cinzas]

```
CellController xadrez = new CellController() {
    @Override
    public int getForeColor(int row, int col) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBackColor(int row, int col) {
        return ((row + col) % 2 == 0) ? 0xffffff : 0xe0e0e0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getChoices(int row, int col) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

[image: marcando células em xadrez]

```
CellController padrao = new CellController() {
    @Override
    public int getForeColor(int row, int col) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBackColor(int row, int col) {
        return (row % 2 == 0) ? 0xffffff : 0xe0e0e0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getChoices(int row, int col) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

[image: padrão: linhas de cores alternadas]

O código que usei para tirar os screenshots segue [neste snippet](https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/snippets/1672601).

Comment: Resolvido @Jefferson Quesado, obrigado pela ajuda. Vou postar a minha implementação (editando a minha pergunta) para que sirva de ajuda para quem precisar.